# Google Play Store: My app page does not show the leaderboard and achievements icons/badges

Tags: android, google-play, leaderboard, achievements

I launched an app on google play store this week. The app uses Google Play Games Leaderboard and Achievements APIs. Should the app page in play store app not show these icons/badges like it does in other apps that use these APIs? Do i need to enable it anywhere?

These are the icons/badges I'm referring to (image below). How do i add/enable these? Do i need to do anything in the app apk to get these?

[image: Missing icons on my app marked in red in this image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had a chat with the Google Play support team. They said that it gets enabled automatically after a certain threshold (a few hundred users from what they said) is reached. So basically no additional configuration/setup is required to start showing the icons. I'm just going to wait a few days and see if it pops up. Will update.

Comment: Did you come to know the exact threshold value. Or any updates ? I already have 200+ players. So curious to know when will the badges appear.

Comment: Unfortunately my app hasn't picked up so much yet and dont have many users. I'm checking regularly and will update once i see them showing up on the page.

Comment: I know it's a lot of time since your last comment, but maybe you remember when did you finally get this achievements mark? For me developer's console shows 21K Play Games users and we still do not have it.

Comment: my app have more than a thousand daily users and after 2 weeks still no icon

Answer (score 0):

I added Google PlayServices at beginning of the year, so its active almost a year.

Currently 330 users are in the leaderboard of my game. But that symbols still not appeared;-(

In general what I can see is that the initial requested acceptance of the PlayServices in my game, is distracting a lot of people. From 10 people who download the game only 3 will register the PlayServices.
Some of the other might even directly deinstall it, not noticing that my game can also used without.

A lot of people dont want it either because of privacy or because they expecting unwanted data traffic.

Comment: there is a auto sign-in option, use ti, helps in my situation